# Getting Invalid Day in Date when using moment.js in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i'm currently using moment.js library to render dates in real time to my users, but after some tests today, i noticed something really weird, when listing all possible days to the user in Firefox, moment.js fails to add days in the date '2015-09-14'.
After searching the developers documentation and the internet, i discovered that you have to pass a ISO8601 valid Date or construct by passing explicit information of the date, but the results continue to confuse me.

Here's some code for understanding:

Working case (creating a moment() instance from current time):

```
var printVar = moment();
var divInfo  = document.getElementById('calendars');
divInfo.innerHTML += "<ul>";

for(var i=0; i<40; i++){
    divInfo.innerHTML += "<li> " + printVar.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + " </li>";            
    printVar = moment(printVar).add(1, 'days');
}

divInfo.innerHTML += "</ul>";
```

My Result:

- 15/10/2015
- 16/10/2015
- 17/10/2015
- 18/10/2015
- 19/10/2015
- 20/10/2015

Weird case #1 (creating a moment() using time with encoding 'YYYY-MM-DD'):

```
var printVar = moment('2015-09-14');

var divInfo  = document.getElementById('calendars');
divInfo.innerHTML += "<ul>";

for(var i=0; i<40; i++){
    divInfo.innerHTML += "<li> " + printVar.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + " </li>";            
    printVar = moment(printVar).add(1, 'days');
}

divInfo.innerHTML += "</ul>";
```

My Result:

- 15/10/2015
- 16/10/2015
- 17/10/2015
- 17/10/2015
- 18/10/2015
- 19/10/2015

Weird case #2 (creating a moment() using explicit constructor like moment([2015, 8, 14])) return the same result:

- 15/10/2015
- 16/10/2015
- 17/10/2015
- 17/10/2015
- 18/10/2015
- 19/10/2015

Firefox version: 40.0.3

Thanks for all the Help!

Comment: Interesting bug, but you definitely should create an Issue on github.. looks really weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be in Brazil!

- Brazil "springs-forward" for [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) at midnight on October 18, 2015.  That is, the clocks tick from `2015-10-17T23:59:59.999` to `2015-10-18T01:00:00.000`.  **There is no midnight on this day in your time zone!**
- Moment still uses the `Date` object for certain operations internally.
- The `Date` object is implemented differently on different browsers when it comes to DST transition edge cases, such as dealing with invalid or ambiguous values.
- Firefox happens to shift *backwards* by an hour when you provide an invalid value.  Other browsers such as Chrome shift *forwards* (which is more sensible IMHO).

Consider that with my time zone set for Brazil where DST occurs (Brasillia, Sao Paulo, etc.):

In FireFox:

[image]

But in Chrome:

[image]

Notice that by shifting backwards instead of forwards, the dates for the middle two values are off by one.

To be clear, this is a browser issue - not a moment issue.  Similar results can be obtained by just using the `Date` object.  Moment *could* detect this issue and compensate, but it currently does not.

The workaround to get consistent behavior (with `Date` or with `moment`) is to use *noon* when working with date-only values.  DST transitions always occur at night, so noon is a safer value to use than midnight.

Firefox:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

instead of

`printVar = moment(printVar.format()).add(1, 'days');`

just do

`printVar.add(1, 'days');`

Example code:

```js
var printVar, divInfo, i;

printVar = moment();
divInfo  = document.getElementById('example-1');

divInfo.innerHTML += "<ul>";
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    divInfo.innerHTML += "<li> " + printVar.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + " </li>";            
    printVar.add(1, 'days');
}
divInfo.innerHTML += "</ul>";


printVar = moment('2015-9-10');
divInfo  = document.getElementById('example-2');
divInfo.innerHTML += "<ul>";
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    divInfo.innerHTML += "<li> " + printVar.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + " </li>";            
    printVar.add(1, 'days');
}

divInfo.innerHTML += "</ul>";


printVar = moment([2015, 8, 14]);
divInfo  = document.getElementById('example-3');
divInfo.innerHTML += "<ul>";

for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    divInfo.innerHTML += "<li> " + printVar.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + " </li>";            
    printVar.add(1, 'days');
}

divInfo.innerHTML += "</ul>";
```

```css
div {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/locale/af.js"></script>
<div id="example-1"></div>
<div id="example-2"></div>
<div id="example-3"></div>
```

Comment: Already did it :/ When passing with a format to the variable, i get a even weirder result like this: 15/10/2015, 16/10/2015, 17/10/2015, 17/10/2015, 17/10/2015, 17/10/2015.